# changing a new of a file a moving to a new directory in Bash

Tags: bash

I am new to Bash.
I would like to write a **script** which has three variables:

1. The old file name
2. The new file name
3. The name of a directory to move the file to

I'm trying to change the name of the file and move it into the directory.
I know that using `mv` can change the name and to move it to other directory.
I know how to do it using commands that I just type in the terminal but I have some trouble to use variables in those commands. The directory is located in the same location as the file and I run the script from there.

Example:

```
old_file="abc"
new_file="cba"
dir="yyy"
```

Result: No more file called `abc` in `.`, but there is a file called `cba` in `./yyy` witch contains the same information that `abc` had.

Comment: is it your home work?

Comment: @sKwa Nope. just practicing for an exam.

Comment: provide the path/filename

Comment: `mv $old_filename $new_dir/$new_filename` ?

Comment: @Aaron, I don't know why it didn't work before, but now it works. maybe because I wrote with `" "` on each variable. thank you :)

Comment: @kicklog you should use the `""` around both file names to avoid errors with spaces

Comment: @kicklog, then its your home work ;)

Comment: @sKwa how can it be hw if its the end of the semester? next time use your brain instead :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to invoke the `mv` command using the script variables. Notice that the variables are between double quotes to avoid bash splitting the names when finding spaces or other special characters.

```
#!/bin/bash

old_file=$1
new_file=$2
dir=$3

mv "$old_file" "$dir"/"$new_file"
```

And you should invoke it as:

```
./script "abc" "cba" "yyy"
```

Finally, notice that the file "abc" must exist in the current directory (the one where the script is), and the folder "yyy" must also exist in the current directory (or be an absolute path).

Comment: maybe a `[ -f "$old_file" ] && mv "$old_file" "$dir"/"$new_file"` ??

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin `mv` catches and reports that error quite well on its own; silently masking the error by not attempting to `mv` and not then providing any error message etc actually seems ill-advised.

Comment: Well you could make the script as complex as you want by checking the file existence and the directory existence but since he said he is new at bash I tried to keep it as simple as possible (only showing the use of variables and the correct double quotation)

Comment: Then we turn it around to `mv "$old_file" "$dir"/"$new_file" || printf "mv failed for '%s'\n" "$old_file"`.